# How to calculate deviation In Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

How to calculate deviation in Jmeter.In graph, we have a deviation shown in Red and as i heard it indicates deviation from the average. Is there any formula to calculate deviation in Jmeter?  also please share why do we calculate deviation in Jmeter? Kindly post your answers. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

standard devaiation(SD) =
[image]
x = particular label's t(Time)
_
x(x bar) = Sum of all time(T) of specific label

n = no of samples

e.g. (time taken by first sample of ***Login*** **-** Sum of all time(T) of ***Login***)^2 / No. of Samples of ***Login***

Hope this will help.